# reloadData for a Table View in a View Controller

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Hello I have a view controller that loads from an xib i created.  It has two toolbars and a table view in that.

I add this too the header file in the ViewController

```
@interface FilterViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
```

When I do

```
[self.tableView reloadData]
```

It does throws up an error and does not build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just making your `UIViewController` conform to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` does not automatically give you a `tableView` reference.

You need to create a tableView `IBOutlet` and connect it in Interface Builder.

Also, why not just inherit `UITableViewController` instead of a `UIViewController`?

Comment: Definitely check that the table view is wired up to an `IBOutlet` that is specified in the view controller's header file.

Comment: yea i have it hooked up to an outlet called theTable, which i syncronise into the class.  But that still does not work.

Comment: I am using a view controller so that i can display the toolbars properly.

Comment: If your `IBOutlet` to the `UITableView` is called `theTable`, then you should be calling `[self.theTable reloadData];`

Comment: @Matt a `UITableViewController` is still a `UIViewController`, it has just implemented a lot of `UITableView` related things by default. There are few reasons to use a regular `UIViewController` over a `UITableViewController` when it's going to control a `UITableView` anyway.